# How to change an assembly attribute of a third-party dll file?

Tags: .net, dll, culture, disassembly

I have a .NET project that refuses to be built in VS2013 because of a referenced library. The problematic library has culture attribute set to neutral. This causes the following error:

```
Invalid argument. Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
Neutral is an invalid culture identifier.
```

Which tools should be used to change the culture attribute, or indeed any other assembly attribute, of a dll file?

I have tried to disassemble and reassemble it with no success:

Using JetBrains dotPeek I get

```
Cryptographic failure while signing assembly 
'...\Athena.AsePCOS.dll' -- 
'Error reading key file '..\..\ASEKey.snk' -- The system cannot find the 
file specified. '
```

and I am not sure where to find this file or if I should create it myself.

I've also tried to use Reflexil tool but I assume it is not meant to be used for editing assembly attributes.

Comment: You don't have the private key that was used to sign the assembly.  Rather a big deal with code that works with smart cards.  The owner of the DLL has it, more than one reason to pick up the phone and ask for help.

Comment: Do I really need that key? I created a dummy key myself and it solved the problem, at least temporarily.